# mysqli multiple query

Tags: php, mysqli

I do following:

```
$query .=" SELECT * , COUNT(PRESENT) FROM seventh_a";
$query .=" WHERE class ='0' AND NAME ='Alexander Kirkby Scherer'";
$query .=" AND PRESENT = 'TS' GROUP BY lesson";

$query = " SELECT * , COUNT(lesson) FROM seventh_a";
$query .=" WHERE class ='0' AND NAME ='Alexander Kirkby Scherer'";
$query .=" GROUP BY lesson";
```

After that I can echo out `$row['COUNT(PRESENT)']` but not `$row['COUNT(lesson)']`.

Can anybody tell me what to do to get both values, so that i am able to work with them?

Answer (score 2):

According to [the man page](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php), if you're using mysqli_multi_query, you can access results from the different queries like so:

> To retrieve the resultset from the first query you can use `mysqli_use_result()` or 
>   `mysqli_store_result()`. All subsequent query results can be processed using 
>   `mysqli_more_results()` and `mysqli_next_result()`.

They give some sample code:

```
$query  = "SELECT CURRENT_USER();";
$query .= "SELECT Name FROM City ORDER BY ID LIMIT 20, 5";

/* execute multi query */
if ($mysqli->multi_query($query)) {
    do {
        /* store first result set */
        if ($result = $mysqli->store_result()) {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
                printf("%s\n", $row[0]);
            }
            $result->free();
        }
        /* print divider */
        if ($mysqli->more_results()) {
            printf("-----------------\n");
        }
    } while ($mysqli->next_result());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use 2 query . Use combine query like this

```
$query .=" SELECT * , COUNT(PRESENT),COUNT(lesson) FROM seventh_a";
$query .=" WHERE class ='0' AND NAME ='Alexander Kirkby Scherer'";
$query .=" AND PRESENT = 'TS' GROUP BY lesson";
```

you will get your result `$row['COUNT(PRESENT)']` and `$row['COUNT(lesson)']`

OR use mysqli's `multi_query` function for this add `;` between queries like this

```
$query .=" SELECT * , COUNT(PRESENT) FROM seventh_a";
$query .=" WHERE class ='0' AND NAME ='Alexander Kirkby Scherer'";
$query .=" AND PRESENT = 'TS' GROUP BY lesson;";   // semicolon here

$query .= " SELECT * , COUNT(lesson) FROM seventh_a";
$query .=" WHERE class ='0' AND NAME ='Alexander Kirkby Scherer'";
$query .=" GROUP BY lesson";
```

Comment: You can use multiple queties if you're using `mysqli_multi_query`: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php